# How to find the array containing the smallest value?

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array of sub-arrays of numbers, and I want to find the sub-array containing the smallest number.

```
data = [
    [10, 11],
    [93, 3], # This is the required sub-array because 3 is smaller than all the other numbers
    [33, 44, 55]
]

# tag the smallest item from each sub-array onto the front, creating a new main array
extendedData = map(lambda x:(min(x), x),data)

# use the fact that when given an array, min() will examine the first element
(smallestValueFromRow, rowContainingSmallestValue) = min(extendedData)

print(rowContainingSmallestValue)
```

Here's a working example: https://www.online-python.com/7O5SceGoEF

Is there a more memory-efficient way to approach this?  The array and sub-arrays could be quite large in practice, and I'm assuming the `map` function makes a copy of the `data` array, with the mapping applied.

Comment: There are no arrays anywhere in this code. We call them *lists*.

Comment: print(min(map(lambda x: x, data)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first solution, using `map`, should not require more than constant extra space, since `map` returns a generator — it doesn’t actually *do* anything until you iterate over it.

However, you can do effectively the same thing with less typing:

```
print(min(data, key=min))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which will return the first list which contains the minimum value:

```
data = [
    [10, 11],
    [93, 3], 
    [33, 44, 55]
]    

smallestNumbersFromEachSubList = [min(subList) for subList in data]
subListContainingTheSmallestNumber = data[smallestNumbersFromEachSubList.index(min(smallestNumbersFromEachSubList))]
print(subListContainingTheSmallestNumber)
```

This would return:

```
[93, 3]
```

Comment: I suppose, since this generates a "list" of the smallest numbers, it won't consume nearly as much memory as my version?

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for a memory-efficient implementation, this approach will be *constant space*

```
min_num = min_idx = float("inf")
for i, nums in enumerate(data):
    local_min = min(nums)
    if local_min < min_num:
        min_idx = i
    min_num = min(min_num, local_min)
print(data[min_idx])
```